# can spark inherit a regular master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

I have an existing mvc app. I've decided that i would like to use spark. My plan is to slowly migrate the whole site to spark. Will i have to create 2 master pages, ie one for .aspx content and one for .spark content. Is there anyway i could use one master page for both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537783/will-the-spark-view-engine-interoperate-with-webforms-master-pages

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two master pages. The syntax is not compatible between view engines.